# Output from a PHP script to C scanf of program

Tags: php, c, bash, file-io, pipe

I wonder how is it possible to pass an output from PHP to scanf of a c program? The normal way of inputing in this C program is to use an `echo -ne "\x0a etc..........." | ./program` on terminal. The thing is that I cannot apply it on PHP. could someone help me? Lets say I want to output the variable $var from PHP to the C program.

Answer (score 0):

Use `popen()` inside the script to run a command with input from the script. To get hex characters, put them inside a double-quoted string, and concatenate them to the variables.

```
$pipe = popen($program, "w");
$vartmp = $passwordHEX . "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00‌\x00\x00x00" . $Pass‌​wordHash;
fwrite($pipe, $vartmp);
pclose($pipe);
```

Comment: Don't try to put a script into a comment. Edit the question.

Comment: Updated the question. So, I think that the problem here is that I want \x00 to be counted by the scanf whereas in this way it doesn't. It's about a buffer overflow so the size is specific. Do these make sense? @barmar

Comment: can I just ouput them in the exact way that bash's echo -ne "...." does?

Comment: `scanf()` is for processing formatted text, not binary data. It can't handle null bytes like that, because in C those are string terminators.

Comment: The code in my answer outputs exactly what bash's `echo -ne` does.

Comment: What do you mean buy that? Then why in echo of bash when I put 11 * \x00  it is accepted whereas if I put just one it's not? I think they are counted but not considered as values, its just empty but if buf[16] is consisted lets say of 5 real chars and 11 null then its full.

Comment: How is it possible to output the same but I get correct message when execute it by echo, but wrong when trying this?

Comment: Don't use `bin2hex()` in the PHP. You want to write the binary, not its hex representation. Hex is just needed in literals, to produce binary data.

Comment: But if you already have binary data, you don't need to convert it back to hex.

Comment: I used bin2hex() to concatenate the whole string in the proper form. I mean in order to inject it all together with the other part

Comment: You don't need to. You're totally confused about the way hex is used in programming. It's used as a way to input binary data from users or display it to users, not as a way to store it. It's not needed for internal communication between components.